# How do I draw an array made bitmap on screen using bitblt?

Tags: c++, mfc, ondraw, bitblt

Instead of drawing using `Moveto` and `LineTo`, I want to use a hand made bitmap, that I will fill with an array that I will create myself, and use that to fill the screen.

Right now, the array is just filled with red,
But when I draw to the screen I get all black.

This is the code:

```
void CCGWorkView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CCGWorkDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    pDCToUse->FillSolidRect(&r, world.bg_color);

    BITMAPINFO bminfo;
    CPaintDC hdc(this);
    CRect rect;
    GetWindowRect(&rect);

    int h = rect.bottom - rect.top,
        w = rect.right - rect.left;
    int *bits = new int[w * h];

    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP bm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, w, h);

    SelectObject(hdcMem, bm);

    bminfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bminfo.bmiHeader);
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = w;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = h;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 1;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 1;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < w * h; i++) {
        bits[i] = RGB(255, 0, 0);
    }

    SetDIBits(hdcMem, bm, 0, h, bits, &bminfo, 0);

    BitBlt(hdc, rect.left, rect.top, w, h, hdcMem, rect.left, rect.top, SRCCOPY);

    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    DeleteObject(bm);
    delete bits;
}
```

Comment: Two points here, first `CPaintDC` paints on the window's client area, therefore you should have called `GetClientRect()` instead of `GetWindowRect()`. Second, you must select `bm` out of `hdcMem`, before destroying any of the two objects - select the previous bitmap (returned by the previous call to `SelectObject()`) into `hdcMem`. Not sure if these will solve your problem though, however the first one is quite likely.

Comment: And forgot to mention, in `BitBlt()' the `x` and 'y' coordinates (destination rectangle), as well as `x1` and `y1` (source rectangle) should all be 0. It will work as is though, because the `top` and `left` coordinates returned by `GetClientRect()` are 0 anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your code.

First, you don’t need `CPaintDC`, as the `pDC` is passed into your `OnDraw()` function.
This may have actually caused your black display, as the newly created DC has a one pixel black-and-white bitmap selected into it, and when you call `CreateCompatibleBitmap()`, that bitmap is also monochrome.

Second, `SetDIBits()` expect `RGBQUAD` colors (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-rgbquad), NOT `RGB`.

And, as Constantine Georgiou suggested, you should de-select your bitmap out of DC before deleting it to avoid resource leaks, even if MFC handles it for you.

Here is modified code:

```
void CMFCApplication1View::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CMFCApplication1Doc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    //pDCToUse->FillSolidRect(&r, world.bg_color);

    BITMAPINFO bminfo;
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);

    int h = rect.bottom - rect.top,
        w = rect.right - rect.left;
    int* bits = new int[w * h];

    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(pDC->m_hDC);
    HBITMAP bm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC->m_hDC, w, h);

    HGDIOBJ hOld = SelectObject(hdcMem, bm);

    bminfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bminfo.bmiHeader);
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = w;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = h;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 1;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 1;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    bminfo.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

    RGBQUAD red = { 0, 0, 255, 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < w * h; i++) {
        bits[i] = *((int*)&red);
    }

    SetDIBits(hdcMem, bm, 0, h, bits, &bminfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    BitBlt(pDC->m_hDC, rect.left, rect.top, w, h, hdcMem, rect.left, rect.top, SRCCOPY);

    SelectObject(hdcMem, hOld);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    DeleteObject(bm);
    delete[] bits;
}
```

Comment: The [`CPaintDC` c'tor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cpaintdc-class#public-constructors) does not create a device context. It simply returns the result from calling [`CWnd::BeginPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cpaintdc-class#public-constructors), which wraps the call to [`BeginPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-beginpaint). That's still a bug, as [`CView::OnDraw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cview-class#ondraw) gets called for reasons other than painting to the screen.